# No error while uploading a file to non-existant FTP path using MSINET

Tags: ftp, upload, vb6, msinet

I am using VB6 and playing with msinet.ocx nowadays. All is fine. I can upload a file, download a file, get size of a file at remote ftp server etc.

Yesterday, I intentionally used a wrong path in "inet1.execute PUT" command. I was expecting to get an error message or error code (inet.responcecode / inet.responceinfo) in statechanged event routine. But all goes well without any error as if the path is valid. Of course nothing happens at server side, No file.

Is it inet expected behaviour or am I missing something?

Thanks,